# What is the name of this property of a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

Let $R$ be a ring. For all $x,y\in R$, there exists a $z\in R$ such that $xy=yz$.

Does this property have a name? I do not assume that multiplication has an identity or that it is commutative, but I do assume that multiplication is associative

Comment: Do you have an example of a ring with this property?

Comment: @uniquesolution All rings that are commutative/division rings.

Comment: @Abe - obviously. But it is only non-trivial when the ring is not commutative. So let me rephrase my question: Do you have a non-trivial example of a ring with this property? i.e., a non-commutative ring which is not a division ring?

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't.

Comment: I see. I think there is little point in asking for a name for something you don't know whether it exists at all, given that in the obvious cases where this "property" holds, it is really not a "property".

Comment: @uniquesolution I respect that opinion.

Comment: Is that any reason you are interested in this particular property?

Comment: This property is equivalent to "$Ry \subseteq yR$ for all $y \in R$" as well as "every right ideal of $R$ is a left (hence two-sided) ideal".

Comment: @Abe for the record, [here are at least three right duo rings that are not division rings and are not commutative.](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84l&L=1&L=2)

Comment: @uniquesolution Granted it is a little awkward that the title seems to “assume there must be a name” but the body says it better by “is there a name.” And asking if a term exists when you don’t have a *single* example doesn’t make much sense, because you don’t know if it is consistent. But invalidating the users question just because the examples aren’t nontrivial enough for you is a little unfriendly.  At any rate, since we know it is in fact an interesting condition, maybe the above doubts about examples can disappear now?  Please consider it, thanks.

Comment: And I need to correct myself above, those are actually the results for left duo rings.  [There is another example in the query for right duo rings](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84r&L=1&L=2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such rings (where $\forall x,y \in R\, \exists z \in R\, xy=yz$) are called "right duo rings". In a right duo ring, every right ideal is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much!